# get a innertext with condition on href value

Tags: javascript

I would like to get innertext of an a element with condition.

```
<a href="www.url.com">text</a>
```

The condition a would like to set is to find innertext of an a element on which the href value start with a certain text.

For example following my example i would like to get output = text for href start with 'www'.

Comment: Please post any attempt you have made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for

`document.querySelector('a[href^=www]')`

The snippet above will query the entire document looking for `a` elements that have a `href` attribute with a value starting with `www`

Have a look here for [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and here for possible [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)